# Checking the google plus availability

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-plus-one, google-plus-signin

In Android,I am using the Google plus interactive post and G+1 button. Before I start the Interactive Posting, I need to make sure if the google Plus app is available in the device. For now, I am using the bellow try catch method to catch the failure. Could you please advice a better way to check the availability of the google plus app availability in the device.

```
    try {
        startActivityForResult(getInteractivePostIntent(msg), REQUEST_CODE_INTERACTIVE_POST);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        toastSimple("You haven't installed google+ on your device");
    }
```

Comment: For interactive post, have you read https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/interactive-post yet?

Answer (score 0):

From the official doc here:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#frequently_asked_questions

The `GooglePlusUtil#checkGooglePlusApp` utility method returns `GooglePlusUtil.SUCCESS` if the Google+ app is installed. If the app is not installed, you can prompt the user to install the app with the `GooglePlusUtil#getErrorDialog` utility method.

```
int errorCode = GooglePlusUtil.checkGooglePlusApp(this);
if (errorCode != GooglePlusUtil.SUCCESS) {
  GooglePlusUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, this, 0).show();
}
```

Comment: I am getting error "Cannot resolve symbol 'GooglePlusUtil' "

Comment: @iappmaker: have you set compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0' in build.gradle file yet?

Comment: I have this issue report to Google, might fix asap.